# Resize background image in html for responsive template

Tags: html, css, image

I'm practicing in making a responsive website my problem is how to resize the image based on the resolution of the webpage?
Here's my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
body {
    background: url("streetlight.png");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    position: absolute;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You looking background image ? or IMG tag ?

Comment: background-size:100% 100%;

Comment: @ShibinRagh background image

Comment: @CullyLarson Oops sorry

Comment: @thenewbie  Did you check my answer ?

Comment: do you mean that you would like to change the resolution of your image (this means change the image) based on the resolution of the screen?

Comment: @web-tiki Yes, change the resolution of the image based on the resolution of the browser/screen

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
body{ 
  background: url(streetlight.png) no-repeat center center fixed; 
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: yes i was just posting this solution because i also faced the similar problem while i am trying to make responsive templates. That is why i remember the solution

Comment: The image fits the whole page it doesn't resize based on the resolution of the browser.